# From my Webserver, Why can I save a file to Linux but not Windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, windows-10, python-requests-html

I have created a simple website to allow users to upload a file.
Then I massage their data and create an output file for them to download.
With my code, on my Linux box, it works and save the file to my local machine.

However, from my Windows PC, it always gives me an `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:/users/mclayton/deliveries_date.xlsx'`

I reversed the `\` to `/` to allow for the os change, and I'm using the absolute path.
Any ideas?
My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

import requests

print('Beginning file download')

url = 'http://5.168.49.100/outputdata/Deliveries_Data.xlsx'

r = requests.get(url)

open(r'c:/users/mclayton/deliveries_date.xlsx', 'wb').write(r.content)

print('Download completed')
```

Comment: Is the webserver running under your user account? If not, it does not have access to your user directory. If it is, you need to redesign your webserver to not rely on access to folders other than its own on your computer, or you're exposing yourself badly to malware.

Comment: The simple and obvious explanation is that `c:/users/mclayton/` does not exist. You don't need a raw string if you are using forward slashes in the Windows path.

Comment: @triplee - well it does exist on my local windows machine.

Comment: @KenWhite - No, it is running under Apache.

Comment: Apache does not run under your individual user account, so your server has no access to that folder. You should not be trying to write to that folder from the server. That folder belongs to you as an individual user on the computer. Write to a folder to which the server account has access instead.

Comment: As an aside, you should [edit] these debugging details into your question. Actual proof that the file exists is better than your say-so; many of our visitors have the weirdest ideas about how what they see in their GUI corresponds to actual file names, and are baffled about e.g. case-sensitive file systems (not that many of those exist anymore). On Windows, ACLs would be another detail to investigate when having thouble with the file system.